# Get the text of td with specific id when checkbox is checked within the same row each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

Is there a way to get the text of a `td` from the same row as a checkbox ,when that checkbox is checked?

For example in this table:

```
<tr id="1">
    <td id="date"> Mon, 20 Feb 2017 </td>
    <td id="from" >mymail@gmail.com </td>
    <td id="subject"> Hello World! </td>
    <td> <input id ={{d.id}} type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
    <td id="date"> Sun, 19 Feb 2017 </td>
    <td id="from" >mymail@gmail.com </td>
    <td id="subject"> Hello again World! </td>
    <td> <input id ={{d.id}} type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"/> </td>
</tr>
```

If I click the checkbox on the second row,I want to alert the subject of that row ,which is "Hello again World".

So far I have tried with `.parent()` , `.siblings()` and `closest()` ,but no luck.

Comment: What are those `{{...}}`? Are you using something like Handlebars?

Comment: You have some ID duplicates which is invalid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd used this way:

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
    <td> Mon, 20 Feb 2017 </td>
    <td>mymail@gmail.com </td>
    <td class="subject"> Hello World! </td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Sun, 19 Feb 2017 </td>
    <td>mymail@gmail.com </td>
    <td class="subject"> Hello again World! </td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" /> </td>
</tr>  
</table>
<script>
  $('#table').on('click',':checkbox',function(){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.subject').text());
  });
</script>
```

PS: i have removed all unused info for this case to be clear

`id` attribute must be unique over whole html document, never use same `id` for multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

A valid HTML shouldn't have duplicate Id's. I have updated your html by replacing Id's with class.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").change(function(index){  
   alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td.subject').text())
  });
})
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/3370/)

Comment: What is needed to `closest('tr')` when target element has id attribute. `find('#subject')` is enough. Also the html has some id.

Comment: both alert are showing same subject text, which is wrong. Anyways I understood Id is duplicated which is not valid.

Comment: actually the above code works just fine for me. I used it to get the td with 'from' id and I am now working on how to get the href from the td with the id 'subject' .

Comment: Yeah, above code will work, but as said a valid HTML shouldn't have duplicate Id. you will find it difficult to maintain your code in future. try using class instead of id, to handle similar scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is using a custom data attribute (note that I fixed the "id" issues from your code):

```js
$("input[name='mycheckbox']").click(function(event){
  var row=$(event.target).data('row');
  console.log(row);
  var subject=$('#'+row+' .subject').text();
  console.log(subject);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="1">
    <td class="date"> Mon, 20 Feb 2017 </td>
    <td class="from" >mymail@gmail.com </td>
    <td class="subject"> Hello World! </td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" data-row="1"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
    <td class="date"> Sun, 19 Feb 2017 </td>
    <td class="from" >mymail@gmail.com </td>
    <td class="subject"> Hello again World! </td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" data-row="2"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute should be unique in document. You can use class attribute instead. However you can select target element by bottom code.

```
$("#2 [name='mycheckbox']").click(function(){
  alert($(this).parent().prev().text());
});
```

```js
$("#2 [name='mycheckbox']").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).parent().prev().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="1">
  <td id="date"> Mon, 20 Feb 2017 </td>
  <td id="from" >mymail@gmail.com </td>
  <td id="subject"> Hello World! </td>
  <td> <input id ={{d.id}} type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
  <td id="date"> Sun, 19 Feb 2017 </td>
  <td id="from" >mymail@gmail.com </td>
  <td id="subject"> Hello again World! </td>
  <td> <input id ={{d.id}} type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works without jquery

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(
   document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]')
).forEach(
   function(i){
      i.onclick = function(){
         alert(this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('#subject').innerHTML)
      }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jvhdx85u/

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trick for this(which i use most often in many other cases)

```
  <tr id="1">
        <td id="date"> Mon, 20 Feb 2017 </td>
        <td id="from" >mymail@gmail.com </td>
        <td id="subject_t1"> Hello World! </td> <!--check the subject id and input id-->
        <td> <input id ="t1" class="your_class" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td id="date"> Sun, 19 Feb 2017 </td>
        <td id="from" >mymail@gmail.com </td>
        <td id="subject_t2"> Hello again World! </td>
        <td> <input id ="t2" class="your_class" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"/> </td>
    </tr>
```

here is the jquery you can use.

```
<script>$(document).on('click','.your_class',function(){
 var checkbox_id = $(this).attr('id'); //getting id of this clicked checkbox
 var subject_id = "#subject_"+checkbox_id; //making subject id from this as we already made a simple pattern for the id of subject
alert($(subject_id).text()); //i am using the text in alertbox you can do what you want with it
});
```